# Editing issues after knife project

Tags: modeling, knife-tool, project

After knife projecting, and heading back into edit mode, I find that all the vertices are invisible, and I get a very peculiar way of moving/editing things which is highly inconvienient.
Here is an example of what happens https://gyazo.com/02085eed7b7fc3adfe1b1ec81ab3244a

Usually I have simply copy and pasted everything onto a new blender file and this has fixed it, however on bigger projects that I am now undertaking it has become highly troublesome to copy and paste many objects and parts without worrying that I've forgotten something, and really it's just become a hassle.

If any of you could help with this it'd be fantastic.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Knife Project* tool automatically switches to Edge select mode.
To switch back to *Vertex select*, use the icons on top left.

Shortcut: <kbd>1</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! This worked.

Comment: Happy to help :). Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2):

Press 1 (not in the numpad)
At some point you pressed 2.
1, 2, 3 change the way you see and act on the mesh
1 = vertices
2 = edges
3 = faces

Comment: Thanks a bunch Daniele